# Blender - Way to quickly search for open solid?

Tags: faces

I just discovered what I thought to be a solid, is an open structure:

[image]

It turns out that there are a lot of locations like this, where I thought had faces, but do not. Is there any quick way to find these all in blender, and created faces over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply putting faces there to cover up the holes would produce messy geometry - because then there would be a lot of inner faces as it seems from the screenshot.

However, at least this helps finding where you have the open faces if they are all structured like that. Because this way you have non manifold geometry and interior faces.

So from the top menu you can choose *Select* > *Select All By Trait* and then either *Non Manifold* or *Interior Faces*, the first only in *Vertex Select* or *Edge Select* mode, the second in all select modes.

You cannot simply hit <kbd>F</kbd> then to fill all the holes, but at least you will find them to then manually "repair" them. I would not only fill the holes, but delete the interior faces as well. If you just selected *Interior Faces* instead of *Non Manifold* you could get rid of those faces immediately by hitting <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Faces*, but then the edges would no longer be non manifold and you couldn't select them auutomatically anymore.

[image: select all by trait]

[image: resulting selection]